# Building maven project with IntelliJ doesn't create JAR

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When running the following command in the terminal, I can see in the target directory the JAR file, whereas when building with IntelliJ I only see the compiled classes.

Why?

[image]

Comment: How do you build with idea ?

Comment: Just "Build Project"

Answer (score 2):

To get the jar built by IDE you need to configure the jar [Artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html#artifact_def) to build:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build your project and execute run actions through Maven, you need to delegate all those actions to Maven with the Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven option located in the Maven settings.

Build a project with Maven #
Click icons general settings svg in the Maven tool window. Alternatively, from the main menu select File | Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment |Build Tools | Maven.

Click Maven and from the list, select Runner.

On the Runner page, select Delegate IDE build/run actions to maven.

more detail see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html)

Comment: So after doing that, I'm still running the build with the way I did? - Since I'd like to run a custom maven command (e.g. skip tests and set profile to prod)